# Do I still need the AcceptedVerbs attribute?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

In WebApi2, do I still need to decorate my methods with the AcceptedVerbs attribute? Or is the HttpPut parameter in the Route attribute sufficient?

```
    [AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
    [Route("api/v1/tokens/current"), HttpPut]
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpPut` is actually a separate attribute here and not a parameter on `RouteAttribute`. For your scenario you could use either `AcceptVerbs` or `HttpPut`, but in general `AcceptVerbs` is helpful when you want to define multiple http methods or custom http methods which by default do not have strongly typed representation in Web API (ex: HttpPut). I would prefer using `HttpPut` in your above scenario.

Comment: Ok, thanks Kiran. So I can drop all the AcceptVerb attributes in my application. They are redundant then.